# How to interact with Existing database with Model through template function in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have an existing table called empname in my postgres database

(Projectid,empid,name,Location) as
(1,101,Raj,India),
(2,201,David,USA)

So in the app console it will have like the following

1)Projectid=Textbox

2)Ops      =(view,insert,Edit)-Dropdown

Case1:
So if i write project id as 1 and select View Result:It will display all the records for Projectid =1(Here 1 record)

Case2:
If i write projectid as 3 and select insert it will ask for all the inputs like empid,name,address and based on that it will update the table .

Case3:
If i write projectid as 2 and select edit.Then it will show all the field for that id and user can edit any column and can save which will update the records in backend for the existing table
If there is not data found for the respective project id then it will display no records found

Please help me on this as I am stuck up with models

Comment: Can Anybody help me on this.I have changed the format a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your models created, the next task should be the form models. I can  identify atleast 3 form classes that you will need to create. One to display the information(case 1), another to collect information(case 2) and the last class to edit the information. Wire up the form to the views and add the urls.
A good reference could be a django a user registration form since it will have all the three cases taken care of.http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/login.html